# jQuery - Morphing button concept - Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have created a simple morphing button concept. Everything seems good. Except from the fact that after opening and closing the button about 4-5 times, everything seems to mess up and get muddled.

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f793yvh5/22/

Here's part of the jQuery:

```
function Morphing( button, container, content) {
    this.button = button;
    this.container = container;
    this.content = content;
    this.overlay = $('div.overlay');
    this.span = $('span.close');

    var self = this; // so you have a reference to this this.

    this.positions = {
        endPosition : {
            top: 100,
            left: '50%',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            marginLeft: -300
        },

        startPosition : {
            top: self.container.css('top'),
            left: self.container.css('left'),
            width: self.container.css('width'),
            height: self.container.css('height'),
            marginLeft: self.container.css('margin-left')
        }
    };

}

Morphing.prototype.startMorph = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.button.on('click', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(200);
        // Work on from here!
        setTimeout(self.containerMove.bind(self), 200);
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.containerMove = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.overlay.fadeIn();
    this.container.addClass('active');

    this.container.animate(this.positions.endPosition, 400, function() {
            self.content.fadeIn();
            self.span.fadeIn();
            self.close();
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.close = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.span.on('click', function() {
        self.content.fadeOut();
        self.span.fadeOut();
        self.overlay.fadeOut();
        setTimeout(self.animateBack.bind(self), 275);
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.animateBack = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.container.animate(this.positions.startPosition, 400, function() {
        self.button.fadeIn(300);
        self.container.removeClass('active');
    });
};
```

The other part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var morph = new Morphing( $('button.morphButton'), $('div.morphContainer'), $('h1.content, p.content') );


    morph.startMorph();

});
```

To sum up, this is what jQuery is doing:

Button is clicked:
1. Button fades out,
2. Container behind the button is therefore visible,
3. Overlay fades in,
4. Container animates to center of screen,
5. Content in container fades in.

When the 'X' is pressed:
1. Content fades out,
2. Overlay fades out,
3. Container animates back to button,
4. Button fades in over the container.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand people down-voting a post without commenting on why they down-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call:

```
Morphing.prototype.close = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.span.on('click', function() {
        self.content.fadeOut();
        self.span.fadeOut();
        self.overlay.fadeOut();
        setTimeout(self.animateBack.bind(self), 275);
    });
};
```

You define a on click for the span in your newContainer.

Add:

```
$.fn.once = function(a, b) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).off(a).on(a,b);
    });
};
```

at the end of your code and then:

```
Morphing.prototype.close = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.span.once('click', function() {
        self.content.fadeOut();
        self.span.fadeOut();
        self.overlay.fadeOut();
        setTimeout(self.animateBack.bind(self), 275);
    });
};
```

and it should be ok.

[Here is an updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f793yvh5/26/)

Comment: Just literally figured it out before you wrote this! Still though, Im confused. Why is this happening? Surely the method for the button being clicked should also do the same thing? Why just the span?

Comment: It is the only element you are defining an on click listener for. And things get weird since in your animate back function you fade in the button, and it is called more than once.

Comment: What about the this.button.on('click', function() { on line 32?

Comment: Just needed to change: this.span.on('click', function() { to this.span.one('click', function() {

Comment: startMorph is only called once at line 78.