# Morphing button - Faster transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay, so my question is probably pretty simple to some of you. But I can't seem to figure this out, so here goes...

I found this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f793yvh5/26/) for a morphing button concept, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267248/jquery-morphing-button-concept-problems). And it's great! Exactly what I need. I'd only like to make one adjustment. The opening transition, when you click on the button - how can I make it faster? So it doesn't 'lag' when it's opening, but instead opens quicker. Which line of JS is responsible for that?

```
function Morphing( button, container, content) {
    this.button = button;
    this.container = container;
    this.content = content;
    this.overlay = $('div.overlay');
    this.span = $('span.close');

    var self = this; // so you have a reference to this this.

    this.positions = {
        endPosition : {
            top: 100,
            left: '50%',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            marginLeft: -300
        },

        startPosition : {
            top: self.container.css('top'),
            left: self.container.css('left'),
            width: self.container.css('width'),
            height: self.container.css('height'),
            marginLeft: self.container.css('margin-left')
        }
    };

}

Morphing.prototype.startMorph = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.button.on('click', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(200);
        // Work on from here!
        console.log(self);
        setTimeout(self.containerMove.bind(self), 200);
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.containerMove = function() {
    var self = this;
        console.log(self);
    this.overlay.fadeIn();
    this.container.addClass('active');

    this.container.animate(this.positions.endPosition, 400, function() {
            self.content.fadeIn();
            self.span.fadeIn();
            self.close();
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.close = function() {
    var self = this;
        console.log(self);
    this.span.once('click', function() {
        self.content.fadeOut();
        self.span.fadeOut();
        self.overlay.fadeOut();
        setTimeout(self.animateBack.bind(self), 275);
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.animateBack = function() {
    var self = this;
        console.log(self);
    this.container.animate(this.positions.startPosition, 400, function() {
        self.button.fadeIn(300);
        self.container.removeClass('active');
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    var morph = new Morphing( $('button.morphButton'), $('div.morphContainer'), $('h1.content, p.content') );


    morph.startMorph();

});

$.fn.once = function(a, b) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).off(a).on(a,b);
    });
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css` at Question and create a stacksnippets to demonstrate current implementation?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting duration at `.startMorph` to less than `200`; for example to `100`, `$(this).fadeOut(100)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The opening transition, when you click on the button - how can I make it faster?

The function of interest is: **Morphing.prototype.containerMove**:

The line of code is: **this.container.animate(this.positions.endPosition, 400, function() {**.

From docs:

> [.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

That means you can act on the second parameter:  try changing it to 100.

The snippet ([updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f793yvh5/27/)):

```js
function Morphing( button, container, content) {
    this.button = button;
    this.container = container;
    this.content = content;
    this.overlay = $('div.overlay');
    this.span = $('span.close');

    var self = this; // so you have a reference to this this.

    this.positions = {
        endPosition : {
            top: 100,
            left: '50%',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            marginLeft: -300
        },

        startPosition : {
            top: self.container.css('top'),
            left: self.container.css('left'),
            width: self.container.css('width'),
            height: self.container.css('height'),
            marginLeft: self.container.css('margin-left')
        }
    };

}

Morphing.prototype.startMorph = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.button.on('click', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(200);
        // Work on from here!
        setTimeout(self.containerMove.bind(self), 200);
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.containerMove = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.overlay.fadeIn();
    this.container.addClass('active');

    this.container.animate(this.positions.endPosition, 100, function() {
        self.content.fadeIn();
        self.span.fadeIn();
        self.close();
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.close = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    this.span.once('click', function() {
        self.content.fadeOut();
        self.span.fadeOut();
        self.overlay.fadeOut();
        setTimeout(self.animateBack.bind(self), 275);
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.animateBack = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    this.container.animate(this.positions.startPosition, 100, function() {
        self.button.fadeIn(300);
        self.container.removeClass('active');
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    var morph = new Morphing( $('button.morphButton'), $('div.morphContainer'), $('h1.content, p.content') );


    morph.startMorph();

});

$.fn.once = function(a, b) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).off(a).on(a,b);
    });
};
```

```css
body {
    background-color: green;
    font-family: 'Cabin';
}

button.morphButton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 150px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #3C6DE2;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
}

div.morphContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 150px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #3C6DE2;
    z-index: 9;
}

button.newButton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%;
    top: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
}

div.newContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%;
    top: 300px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: /*#3C6DE2*/black;
    z-index: 9;
}

div.active {
    z-index: 30;
}

h1, p {
    display: none;
    margin: 50px;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}

p {
    color: white;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

span.close {
    display: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 40px;
    top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    transition:color 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.2s;
}

span.close:hover {
    color: red;
}

div.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button class="morphButton">Terms & Conditions</button>

<div class="morphContainer">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <h1 class="content">Terms & Conditions </h1>
    <p class="content"> Pea horseradish azuki bean lettuce avocado asparagus okra. Kohlrabi radish okra azuki bean corn fava bean mustard tigernut juccama green bean celtuce collard greens avocado quandong fennel gumbo black-eyed pea. Grape silver beet watercress potato tigernut corn groundnut. Chickweed okra pea winter purslane coriander yarrow sweet pepper radish garlic brussels sprout groundnut summer purslane earthnut pea tomato spring onion azuki bean gourd. </p>
</div>

<button class="newButton">New</button>

<div class="newContainer">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <h1 class="newContent">New Stuff</h1>
    <p class="newContent">Pea horseradish azuki bean lettuce avocado asparagus okra. Kohlrabi radish okra azuki bean corn fava bean mustard tigernut juccama green bean celtuce collard greens avocado quandong fennel gumbo black-eyed pea. Grape silver beet watercress potato tigernut corn groundnut. Chickweed okra pea winter purslane coriander yarrow sweet pepper radish garlic brussels sprout groundnut summer purslane earthnut pea tomato spring onion azuki bean gourd.</p>
</div>




<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Consider removing `console.log(self)` calls, which effect rendering at stacksnippets window, or unchecking show console at stacksnippets

Comment: @guest271314 You are right. Thanks. In any case I added a reference to the updated jsfiddle.

Comment: That's it, yup! Thank you, gaetanoM.